# Unable to get servletcontext path in jsf

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, servletconfig

I have written a liferay richfaces portlet. But iam not able to get the css path or images in the web-inf folder.
My portlet config is

```
 <portlet>
    <portlet-name>testLR6_PB3_RF4</portlet-name>
    <instanceable>true</instanceable>

    <render-weight>1</render-weight>
    <ajaxable>true</ajaxable>
    <header-portlet-css>/resources/css/style.css</header-portlet-css>
        <header-portlet-javascript>/js/eims.js</header-portlet-javascript>
        <footer-portlet-javascript>/js/fileupload.js</footer-portlet-javascript>
  </portlet>
```

and in my jsf page

```
<link href="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<div class="floatleft1"><img src="${facesContext.externalContext.requestContextPath}/resources/images/eims_logo.jpg"  /></div>
```

how to get the resources path.

this my java servletcontext code

```
FacesContext context = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance();
        ServletContext servletContext= (ServletContext) context.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContext();
        String path=servletContext.getRealPath("/");
        MainBean mainBean = new MainBean();
        mainBean.getUserBean().setUserPath(path);
```

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Have a look at [how can i have access to my files that placed in WEB-INF folder](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10437565/748437). It might be of help. Besides, if you are using JSF 2.0, Facelets, you can simply get your context root in your jsf pages as

```
<ui:param name="root" value="#{request.contextPath}" />
```

and wherever you need to access files inside your context root, you may access them as(hypothetical example)

```
<img src="#{root}/resources/images/sample.jpg" />
```

At the java side, you can get the context path as

```
String contextPath = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getContextName();
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: still iam not able to get the image

Comment: Can you post your updates here? As in what is the change you did now?

Comment: <ui:param name="root" value="#{request.contextPath}" />
<h:head>
<title>Welcome to swd</title>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-1" />

<link href="../css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />

<title>Untitled Document</title>
<link href="#{root}/resources/css/style.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
</h:head>

Comment: The above code does not have reference of the image or img tag which you are not able to get. Can you paste the code for the image tag that is not being displayed?

Comment: Thanks @vagabond its my fault i placed the resources folder in webinf instead of web content folder