# JSP / Css not taken account

Tags: html, css, jsp

I am developping a JSP page and I would like to import a basic css file for my page.
Here is the code of the jsp :

```
<%@ page contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" language="java" %>
<%@taglib uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix="c"%>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home</title>
        <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/WEB-INF/Css/Home.css" />
    </head>

    <body>
        TOTO !!!!!
    </body>
</html>
```

And here is my css :

```
body {
    background-color: black;
}
```

The problem is that the css is not taken account.
Do you know the problem ?

Answer (score 0):

Any content inside `WEB-INF` is not directly accessible in the browser .

So you can place the `css` file outside of it . namely under the folder named `css` inside your web pages

And access it as,

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/Home.css" />
```

Read [how can i have access to my files that placed in WEB-INF folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10437565/how-can-i-have-access-to-my-files-that-placed-in-web-inf-folder) to know more on this

Update:

```
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>default</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jpg</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.js</url-pattern>
    <url-pattern>*.css</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

Comment: Oh ok I didn't know that, so I did like you but the css is still not taken account.

Comment: can you elaborate . where have you placed the css and how did you try to access it ?

Comment: Under "webapp", I created a folder named "Css". And I put "Home.css" into it. In the jsp file, I put <link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="/Css/Home.css" />

Comment: And where is your `jsp` file ? it would be easy if you update your question with image of your project structure ?

Comment: Sorry I do not have the possibility to put an image. But the jsp file is into webapp/WEB-INF/Pages/

Comment: check my update . add those things to your `web.xml` to allow static resources inside `web-inf`

Comment: I did but it doesn't fix the problem, maybe if I put my pages under webapp directly it could work ? I would have webapp/css and webapp/pages

Comment: Yes it will work in the case you said . but even the above thing should work . Have you checked your browser console ?

Comment: Ok that works by putting "<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/Css/Home.css"/>".  Thanks for your help ;)

Comment: Consider upvoting or accepting the answer if it helped you . so that it would help others